# Fill RecyclerView with days array

Tags: java, android, jodatime

Hello im trying to create custom calendar view with Recycler View . The problem is I didn’t find any solutions how is possible to fill vertical recycler view with dates in year like in this IPhone app. Please show me some samples how it possible to fill Recycler View with days array and scroll it to any year I want (i will use loadMoreListener).

I can not add images so here is the link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8plu.jpg

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use gridLayoutManager

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, number_of_columns));
```